# Nested loop to create list always creates new line in the middle of string

Tags: python

I'm trying to:

1. import two lists
2. write the word from the first list
3. insert a 4bit 4 digit number after (0-9999)
4. write the word from the second list
5. repeat for the first word until 9999
6. start next word (10000 lines later)

output should look like

```
item10000item2
item10001item2
```

Instead my output in my list is:

```
item1
0000item2

item1
0001item2
```

...

I just need the items on the same line. Any tips? Heres my code:

```
file1 = open("5.txt", "r")
file2 = open("6.txt", "r")

file1_list = file1.readlines()
file2_list = file2.readlines()

with open("newList.txt", "w") as f:
    for item in file1_list:
        for item2 in file2_list:
            for num in range(0,10000):
                f.writelines("%s" % item +"{0:04}".format(num)+ "%s\n" % item2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `newlines` could be the results of `\n` in the string after reading using `readlines`.

You can strip newline using `rstrip`. This results in

```py
f.writelines("%s" % item.rstrip() +"{0:04}".format(num)+ "%s\n" % item2.rstrip())
```